# Completing a Cayley table with few given spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

\begin{array}{ccc}
 * & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{6} \\
 \textbf{1} & 1 & & & & & \\ 
\textbf{2} & & & & & 1 & \\
\textbf{3} & & & 1 & & 2 \\
\textbf{4} & & & & & & & \\
\textbf{5} & & & & & & \\
\textbf{6} & & & & & & 1 
\end{array}

need help figuring out the rest of the table

Comment: is * commutative?

Comment: We were not given anything except a hint of first proving 1 is the identity and then find the inverse of each

Comment: @GitGud Luckily, it can be deduced from the table.

Comment: @rschwieb I was unaware that Cayley table implied that we're in a group. Thanks.

Comment: @GitGud Are you a magma theorist, or something? :)

Comment: @rschwieb I don't even what you're talking about. That should answer your question.

Comment: @GitGud I was just trying to guess what generalization of groups you defaulted to, when reading the question. [Magma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)).

Comment: @rschwieb I didn't kow the word magma for grupoid, thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible as written. 3, 4, and 6 are elements of order 2. 2 and 5 are inverses of each other. So it looks like this group is isomorphic to S3, and 1, 2 and 5 should form a subgroup of order 3. Yet 3*5=2. Where has my thinking gone wrong?

Comment: @JoshB. I think you might be right (I ran across an inconsistency that I incorporated into my pos below.)

Comment: @Ashley:  Is this definitely supposed to be the Cayley table of a group?  (I would assume so for the tags, but you don't actually say in your question.)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: 1 is the identity because the identity is the only idempotent element in a group.

Edit: (I had some nonsense here before.)

Don't forget that the table for a group can only have symbols appear once in each column and row. Also don't forget that the only orders possible are 1,2,3,6. (You can use this to eliminate the possibility that $5^3=1$, thus this group is cyclic.)

This question: [About group multiplication table](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287278/about-group-multiplication-table/287290#287290) has helpful tips in the answers, along these lines.

---

OK, I'm starting to not believe in this problem (if we're in a group). Looking only at the powers of 5, we know $5^2\neq1$ (since $5*2=1$) and we know that $5^3\neq1$ (since $5^3=1\implies 2*5^3=5^2=2$, a contradiction with $3*5=2$) thus $5^6=1$.

But then, multiplying with 2's, $3*5=2 \implies3=2^2$. But then $5^6=1\implies 5^2=2^4\implies 5^2=3^2$, but $3^2=1$, a contradiciton with $5^2\neq 1$.

---

TaraB pointed out that $5^6=1$ regardless of the order of $5$, and so you can skip to the final contradiction directly!

Comment: I think you're right, but note that $5^6 = 1$ regardless, since the group has order $6$, so it's not necessary to bother arguing that $5^3\neq 1$.

Comment: It doesn't mean that it has order $6$.  But $a^m = 1$ doesn't mean that $m$ is the _order_ of $a$, just that the order of $a$ divides $m$.

Comment: @TaraB Oh I see what you mean now. I had been away from the problem for too long.

Comment: @TaraB and I forgot to say thanks! I'll have to see if I make this "case-by-case which becomes unnecessary in the last case" mistake very often :)